# Problem in printing angle brackets using the xml-builder node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, xml-builder

I am creating an xml file using "xml-builder" node module. But when I tried to write angle brackets ("<" or ">"), I got characters like "<" and ">". The code is as follows:

```
let builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
let name = "ABC";
let xml = builder.create('Slides');
xml.ele('props',"Hello").up();
xml.ele('name',"<Hello> "+name+" </Hello>").up();
xml.end({ pretty: true });
console.log(xml.toString())
```

The output is as follows:

```
<Slides>
  <props>Hello</props>
  <name>&lt;Hello&gt; ABC &lt;/Hello&gt;</name>
</Slides>
```

What should I do to get `<` or `>` printed instead of `&lt;` or `&gt;` ?

Comment: Replace them with `&lt;` etc...

Comment: Still not getting desired output

Comment: please review my answer @KushagraSinha , leave a comment if it doesn't work or accept it if it does

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm module [decode-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decode-html) that will handle the same use case as your.

```
var decode = require('decode-html');

console.log(decode('&lt;div class="hidden"&gt;NON&amp;SENSE&apos;s&lt;/div&gt;'));
// -> '<div class="hidden">NON&SENSE\'s</div>'
```

Comment: Still not getting desired output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is you are attempting to create a child element in an incorrect way, by passing some xml in the `value` field of `xml.ele`. The module is correctly escaping your angle brackets.

What you need to do is create another element named `Hello` and append it to the `name` element. You can do this by either chaining your `.ele` calls or using their return values.

Here is the correct code:

```
let builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
let name = "ABC";
let xml = builder.create('Slides');
xml.ele('props',"Hello");
xml.ele('name')
   .ele("Hello", name);
xml.end({ pretty: true });
console.log(xml.toString())
```

Output:

```
<Slides>
  <props>Hello</props>
  <name>
    <Hello>ABC</Hello>
  </name>
</Slides>
```

Comment: Sir, actually I have to create "cdata" section in the xml file. Ex: "<notestext><![CDATA[{Notes Text}]]></notestext>". How to create that cdata section?

Comment: See https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki#cdata-nodes or ask a different question